# Find elements of a list with a given sum

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to pick all possible sublists of a given list of integers so that the sum of the sublist elements is a fixed value n, in terms of the original positions of the sublist elements.

For example, with

```
list={2,1,11,3,10,7,7,9,4};
n=10;
```

I hope to get

```
{{5},{2,8},{4,6},{4,7},{1,2,6},{1,2,7},{1,2,4,9}}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), correct?

Comment: @ChipHurst Well, NP-hardness implies absolutely nothing for processing a list of 9 elements, or any reasonably small fixed size, actually.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This culls subsequences whose sum exceeds `n`, to limit somewhat the exponential growth of the possible subsequences:

```
subs[list_, n_] := 
 If[#1 == n, #2, Nothing] & @@@ 
  Fold[Function[{x, a}, 
    Join[x, (If[#1 + a[[2]] > n, 
         Nothing, {#1 + a[[2]], Append[#2, a[[1]]]}] & @@@ 
       x)]], {{0, {}}}, Transpose@{Range@Length@list, list}]
```

It uses `Fold` to update a list of subsequences with each number in the list. Only subsequences with sums less than or equal to `n` are retained. It therefore assumes that the list elements are non-negative. At the end, subsequences with sums less than `n` are removed.

This makes use of the recently added `Nothing` object, which removes itself from lists. I like `Nothing` (which does not mean that I don't like anything).

Answer (score 9):

Check out the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21105/solving-variant-of-the-knapsack-money-changing-problem), by @s0rce and @DanielLichtblau, for an ingenious use of `FrobeniusSolve`.

```
KnapsackLikeProblem[list_List, n_Integer] :=
   With[{s = FrobeniusSolve[list, n]},
        Map[Flatten[Position[#, 1]] &, Pick[s, Map[Max, s], 1]]
   ]
```

For very large lists, the number of Frobenius solutions can be very large. In this case, the technique by @MarkAdler may be more appropriate.

**Edit**

Prompted by @MarkAdler's comment that `FrobeniusSolve` is slow, I adapted another knapsack [response](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20743/variant-of-the-cutting-stock-problem-in-mathematica/20752#20752) from @DanielLichtblau. Using `Reduce` is quite a bit faster, for this problem.

```
DanielSubsetSum[list_List, n_Integer] :=
   Block[{c, v, s},
      c = Array[v, Length[list]];
      s = c /. {ToRules[Reduce[
         Join[Map[1 >= # >= 0 &, c], {Total[c] >= 1, c.list == n}],
         c, Integers]]};
      Map[Flatten[Position[#, 1]] &, s]
   ]
```

Comment: Actually this solution seems to only generate about twice as many intermediate solutions as mine does for large lists, so the space used doesn't seem to be an issue. However the `FrobeniusSolve` is much slower than my solution for some reason, taking about 50 times as long. Also while mine works with zeros, `FrobeniusSolve` will bail if any of the elements are zero.

Comment: `Reduce` is indeed much faster. It is now only 10-20 times slower than the direct approach.

Comment: Also this one works with zeros _and_ negative numbers.

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {2, 1, 11, 3, 10, 7, 7, 9, 4};
n = 10;
```

---

**Brutal brute force** (because it's more brutal than a regular brute force)

```
Pick[Range@Length@list, #, 1] & /@ 
 Tuples[{0, 1}, 
   Length@list][[Flatten@
    Position[Tuples[{0, 1}, Length@list].list, n]]]
```

> {{5}, {4, 7}, {4, 6}, {2, 8}, {1, 2, 7}, {1, 2, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 9}}

*Warning:* Fails for `Length@list > 24` due to lack of memory.

---

### A more reasonable way using the same approach (and a proper answer)

```
Pick[Range@Length@list, #, 1] & /@ 
 Select[FrobeniusSolve[list, n], Max@# == 1 &]
```

> {{5}, {4, 7}, {4, 6}, {2, 8}, {1, 2, 7}, {1, 2, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 9}}

---

**The use of `IntegerPartitions` seems natural:**

This gives the partitions of `n` into elements from `list`:

```
elem = Select[IntegerPartitions[n, All, list], sublist2Q[list, #] &]
```

> {{4, 3, 1, 2}, {9, 1}, {7, 3}, {7, 1, 2}, {7, 3}, {7, 1, 2}, {10}}

where [`sublist2Q`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100797/22013) is

```
sublist2Q[l_List, {s___}] := 
 MatchQ[l, {OrderlessPatternSequence[s, ___]}]
```

To find the positions of elements of `elem`:

```
pos = Table[Sort@Flatten@(FirstPosition[list, #] & /@ elem[[i]]), {i, 1, Length@elem}]
```

> {{1, 2, 4, 9}, {2, 8}, {4, 6}, {1, 2, 6}, {4, 6}, {1, 2, 6}, {5}}

This could be sorted by length:

```
SortBy[pos, Length]
```

> {{5}, {2, 8}, {4, 6}, {4, 6}, {1, 2, 6}, {1, 2, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 9}}

There's an ambguity with the repeating elements, i.e. `7` in this case: `{4, 6}` occurs twice in `pos`, as well as `{1, 2, 6}`. I guess this would need further processing.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers suggested the following:

```
list={2,1,11,3,10,7,7,9,4};
n = 10;
m=Length[list];

Sort[(Times[Range[m],#)& /@ Select[FrobeniusSolve[list,n],Max[#]==1&]) /. {0->Nothing}]
```

> {{5},{2,8},{4,6},{4,7},{1,2,6},{1,2,7},{1,2,4,9}}

Thanks.

Slightly shorter is

```
Sort[Pick[Range[m],#,1]& /@ Select[FrobeniusSolve[list,n],Max[#]==1&]]
```