# Project Euler (memory and speed issues)

Tags: memory, performance-tuning, project-euler

Let n be a positive integer. An integer triple (a, b, c) is called a factorisation triple of n if:

1 ≤ a ≤ b ≤ c
 a·b·c = n.

Define f(n) to be a + b + c for the factorisation triple (a, b, c) of n which minimises c / a. One can show that this triple is unique.

For example, f(165) = 19, f(100100) = 142 and f(20!) = 4034872.

Find f(43!).

Above is the question. You can see my solution below:

```
 f[n_] := Module[{lis1, lis2, lis3, pos, cand, filt}, 
      lis1 = Subsets[Divisors[n], {3}]; lis2 = Times @@@ lis1; 
      pos = Position[lis2, n]; cand = Extract[lis1, pos]; 
      filt = ( #[[3]] / #[[1]] ) & /@ cand; 
      Plus @@ (Extract[cand, Position[filt, Min[filt]]] // Flatten)]
```

Let's test it:

```
f[165]
```

> 19

```
f[100100]
```

> 142

The code is relatively fast even for n as large as 10!

```
f[10!]//Timing
```

> {2.698817, 462}

The problem arises if I try to compute `f[20!]`, I run out of memory. Any tips to circumvent this memory issue will be greatly appreciated. I know my code is straight-up brute force and certainly not the best way to go about this, but it gives the right answer when it works (doesn't run out of memory). Also, the idea is to get the answer in about a minute or less. Thanks.

Edit:

Ok, so I've made progress with the memory issue using Mr. Wizard's advise in the comment.
Of course it's still going to be slow unless one can find a way to generate only `Subsets` for which the product of the elements equals `n`. It would be great if `Subsets` had a 4th `Option` that accepts predicates. For now here's the updated code:

```
f[n_, incr_, end_] := 
 Module[{lis1, pos, cand = {}, filt, div = Divisors[n]}, 
   Do[lis1 = 
     Select[Subsets[div, {3}, {i, i + incr}] // Quiet, Times @@ # == n &]; 
    cand = {cand, lis1}, {i, 1, end, incr}]; 
   cand = Flatten[cand] ~ Partition ~ 3; 
   filt = ( #[[3]] / #[[1]] ) & /@ cand; 
   Plus @@ (Extract[cand, Position[filt, Min[filt]]] // Flatten)] ~
  Monitor ~ i
```

Usage:

```
f[11!,500000,10^15]

(* 1026 *)
```

Now the problem is speeding this code up.

Comment: Don't generate your `Subsets` all at once; take advantage of the third parameter of `Subsets` to generate a portion of the subsets and work with that.  For example `Subsets[Range@6, {3}, {1, 10}]`, then `Subsets[Range@6, {3}, {11, 20}]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks for the tip, I'll work on that now.

Comment: Rather than generating all three-element subsets of divisors--the vast majority of which will not yield a product equal to $n$--think about how to generate a smaller list of candidates. Isn't the main point of Project Euler to get you to think about the nature of the problem rather than apply inefficient brute force tactics?

Comment: Also might want to have a peek [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21098/find-the-a-factor-of-an-integer-which-is-nearest-to-another-integer/21120#21120). It's a similar problem at heart (for all I know motivated by the same PE problem).

Comment: _"I know my code is straight-up brute force and certainly not the best way to go about this, but it gives the right answer when it works (doesn't run out of memory)."_ -- I think you completely misunderstood the whole point of Project Euler. Of course you won't be able to bruteforce problems above twenty! What PE is about is finding the most suitable approach and this often requires a deeper insight into the problem.

Comment: @Federico, with all due respect I completely understand the whole point of PE. My question initially asked about the memory issues which in fact has been solved thanks to input from Mr. Wizard. What you don't understand about PE is that in most cases a brute-force approach helps you realize where the bottleneck is and where you need to focus more. Whenever I ask PE questions it's usually to learn how to improve my *Mathematica* skills. Thanks.